# Why are overlapping alpha textures cutting each other off?

Tags: texturing, transparency

Hi I have a simple plane with a alpha texture of a chainlink as its material. I have set up the situation where two of the same planes are overlapping each other. However it appears that one of the plane is covering the other with its transparent part of the texture. I was able to fix this with the EEVE engine but I would like to use CYCLES for rendering. Is there a way to fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Huh...did you confirm that the intersecting plane is obscured in the actual Cycles render, not just the render preview?
In my experience, I wasn't successful using alphas with Evee without mixing transparent materials, but you seem to have succeeded with just a Principled shader

Comment: yes i can confirm that with actual rendering the texture is cut off with cycles engine.